# Importing points into WirePolyLine

Tags: python, pycharm, abaqus

I am working on creating a wire poly line in Abaqus and can't manage to add points to my wire.

```
# Define the modelname
modelname = "SpineModel"

# Define list with with partnames
PartNames = ["C7", "L1", "L2", "L3", "L4", "L5", "S1", "T1", "T2", "T3", "T4", "T5", "T6", "T7", "T8", "T9", "T10",
             "T11", "T12"]

for i in range(19):
    # Define CoG [x,y,z] coordinates of each vertebrae
    CoG_OldX = mdb.models[modelname].parts[PartNames[i]].features['CoG'].xValue
    CoG_OldY = mdb.models[modelname].parts[PartNames[i]].features['CoG'].yValue
    CoG_OldZ = mdb.models[modelname].parts[PartNames[i]].features['CoG'].zValue
    CoG_OldXYZ = [CoG_OldX, CoG_OldY, CoG_OldZ]

# Print CoG to check the values
    print(CoG_OldXYZ)

    Spline_OLD = mdb.models[modelname].parts[PartNames[i]].WirePolyLine(mergeType=IMPRINT, meshable=False,
                                                                        points=CoG_OldXYZ)
```

After I run this code, I receive an error;
TypeError: points[0]; found float, expecting tuple

However, when I print CoG_OldXYZ, it does print the desired coordinates (19 times x,y,z coordinates).

When I replace "Spline_OLD" with the following, the code runs as I want:

```
Spline_OLD = mdb.models[modelname].parts[PartNames[i]].WirePolyLine(mergeType=IMPRINT, meshable=False,
                                                                         points=(
                                                                            [12.31, -127.52, -467.5],
                                                                           [14.2, -120.15, -484.72],
                                                                          [16.52, -112.85, -502.51],
                                                                         [13.43, -107.49, -520.53],
                                                                        [3.66, -103.59, -536.55],
                                                                       [-11.15, -101.88, -551.4],
                                                                      [-24.81, -100.96, -566.95],
                                                                     [-34.72, -101.45, -585.07],
                                                                    [-38.81, -103.47, -605.76],
                                                                   [-37.71, -107.53, -627.81],
                                                                  [-27.91, -112.2, -649.67],
                                                                 [-14.15, -116.35, -670.89],
                                                                [2.91, -120.57, -691.64],
                                                               [19.53, -123.48, -716.06],
                                                              [28.89, -128.22, -745.13],
                                                             [31.48, -130.96, -777.89],
                                                            [26.69, -129.92, -810.52],
                                                           [16.55, -116.49, -838.38],
                                                          [11.82, -93.95, -853.25]))
```

Why can't I use "CoG_OldXYZ" as points for my WirePolyLine? What am I currently doing wrong?

Comment: Or isnt it possible at all the way I wrote it?

Answer (score 0):

The error itself says about what wrong you are doing, if you observe and try to understand. 
Anyways, I found this from Abaqus Scripting Reference Guide,

> **points** 
> A tuple of point pairs, each pair being itself represented by a tuple.

This means atleast 2 points you must provide to create the `WirePolyLine`. Hence, when you were passing multiple points at once, the code was running correctly.
Now, in `for` loop you can save the points in a list and after the `for` loop, you can use `WirePolyLine` method and pass that list as argument. Please refer following example:

```
cog_points = []
for part in PartNames:
    # Define CoG [x,y,z] coordinates of each vertebrae
    CoG_OldX = mdb.models[modelname].parts[parts].features['CoG'].xValue
    CoG_OldY = mdb.models[modelname].parts[parts].features['CoG'].yValue
    CoG_OldZ = mdb.models[modelname].parts[parts].features['CoG'].zValue
    cog_points.append([CoG_OldX, CoG_OldY, CoG_OldZ])

for part in PartNames:
    Spline_OLD = mdb.models[modelname].parts[part].WirePolyLine(mergeType=IMPRINT, meshable=False,
                                                                        points=cog_points)
```

Comment: Thank you! I still had some errors but found that my code works if I use "extend" instead of "append"!